# prime number NOT working for certain values

Tags: java, windows

The task is to find the prime number at a given number. Here is the code

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Queue {
    private static int number = 0;
    private static int prime;

    public static void calculatePrime(int p) {
        while (prime <p) {
            if (number % 2 != 0) 
                number++;
                prime++;

            {
                number++;

            }

        }
        System.out.println(number );
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        calculatePrime(10001);

    }

}
```

when the input value is 3 it prints out the correct value of 5 but when the input value is 10001 it prints out a number other than 104743

Comment: Time to run the code through a debugger, no?

Comment: Try your code with `5`.  Please note that not all odd numbers are prime.

Comment: ahhhhhhhhhh I didn't even think about that.

Comment: Your code structure is very confusing. Why is `prime++;` nested the same as the first `number++;` when it is not part of the `if` statement? Why is the second `number++;` inside `{}` braces? The code structure almost makes it look like those braces are part of the `if` statement. Also, why are `prime` and `number` static fields, and not local variables?

Comment: What @Andreas said, plus the algorithm is both inefficient and wrong.

Comment: What do you mean by "the prime number _at_ a given number"?

Answer (score 1):

Here's your `calculatePrime` method as the compiler sees it:

```
public static void calculatePrime(int p) {

    while (prime <p) {

        if (number % 2 != 0) 
            number++;

        prime++;
        number++;

    }

    System.out.println(number );
}
```

You could use something like this:

```
public static void calculatePrime(int p) {
    int primeCandidate = p;

    while (!isPrime(primeCandidate)) {
        primeCandidate++;
    }

    System.out.println(number );
}
```

And you'll need a method to return true if the candidate is a prime. There are loads of these available for the small price of a google search.